# spring boot how to append an item to a List with jpa queries

Tags: spring, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In a Spring Boot Kotlin project I am working on there is a MongoRepository for a type called Request that has a property called `messages` of type `List<Message>`, MongoRepository uses JPA queries
I want to have a method which appends a message to `messages` but I can't seem to find how to do that.

Is there a good way to do this or will I need to read the Request, manipulate it in normal code and then write it back to the database?